# Get the text from a Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: jquery, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

When submitting a form, I need the text value of the selected item in my dropdown list. My model just consists of a StatusID and a Description.

The text for the dropdown list is displayed properly and when I submit the form and am getting the associated value for the StatusID property, but the Description property is null.

I added a JS function with jQuery when the form is submitted, to retrieve the associated text value for my model at:

```
var selTypeText = $("#StatusID option:selected").text();
```

But, it never gets inside the JS function to hit that breakpoint.

**What am I missing to get it to execute the JS function?**

Here is my View:

```
@model YeagerTechModel.Status
@using YeagerTechResources
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "check for DDL";
}
<h2>
    "Dropdownlistfor retrieval"</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddSingleStatus", "Status", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="display-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.Description);
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.StatusID, new SelectList((YeagerTechModel.Status[])ViewData["statuses"], "StatusID", "Description"));
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.StatusID)
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value='@Resources.Add' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}

<script>
$(function () {
    $("form").submit(function(){
        var selTypeText= $("#StatusID option:selected").text();
        $("#Description").val(selTypeText);           
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is the pertinent source code before submitting the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>check for DDL</title>
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link href="/Content/kendo/2013.1.703/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Content/kendo/2013.1.703/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Content/kendo/2013.1.703/kendo.blueopal.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Content/kendo/2013.1.703/kendo.dataviz.blueopal.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Scripts/kendo/2013.1.703/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/kendo/2013.1.703/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/kendo/2013.1.703/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

<h2>
    "Dropdownlistfor retrieval"</h2>
<form action="/Status/AddSingleStatus?HttpMethod=POST&amp;InsertionMode=Replace&amp;LoadingElementDuration=0" id="form0" method="post"><div class="validation-summary-valid" id="validationSummary"><ul><li style="display:none"></li>
</ul></div>    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="display-label">
                    <label for="Description">Description</label>;
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <select id="StatusID" name="StatusID"><option value="1">Not Started</option>
<option value="2">In Progress</option>
<option value="3">Completed</option>
<option value="4">Deferred</option>
<option value="8">Reassigned</option>
<option value="9">NonIssue</option>
<option value="10">In Review</option>
<option value="11">Non Starter</option>
<option value="13">Post Review</option>
<option value="14">Reassigned</option>
</select>;
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" id="StatusID_validationMessage"></span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value='Add' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form><script type="text/javascript">


<script>
$(function () {
    $("form0").submit(function(){
        var selTypeText= $("#StatusID option:selected").text();
        $("#Description").val(selTypeText);           
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value is not being posted because you're missing an HTML control for the `Description` property.

In your section:

```
            <div class="display-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.Description);
            </div>
```

You should add a control (`Hidden` or `TextBox` with a `readonly` attribute, as you prefer), like this:

```
            <div class="display-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.Description)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Description, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
            </div>
```

If you don't want to display the selected value in an additional control:

```
            <div class="display-label" style="display:none;">
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Description)
            </div>
```

Also, you have a small typo in your jQuery event handler:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    // Here says "form0", it should be: "#form0"
    $("form0").submit(function(){
        var selTypeText= $("#StatusID option:selected").text();
        $("#Description").val(selTypeText);           
    });
});
</script>
```

Alternatively, you could use asymptoticFault's advice and retrieve the description in your server-side code using the posted `StatusID`. This has the added bonus of being less vulnerable to possible manipulations by the user before your form reaches the server.

Comment: I updated my answer to highlight a small typo in one of your jQuery selectors. Glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

Try attaching a click handler to the button instead:

```
$(':submit').click(function () {
    var selTypeText= $("#StatusID option:selected").text();
    $("#Description").val(selTypeText);  
});
```

Alternatively, you could just retrieve the description server-side using the id.  Recreate the list you are storing in `ViewData["statuses"]` and do something like:

```
// where list holds the same list that was set to ViewData["statuses"]
list.Where(x => x.StatusID == idFromPost).First().Description
```

Comment: It works via the server side method, but still doesn't get into the JS method on the client. I was hoping to use the client methodology since I wouldn't have to go back to the database to repopulate the ViewData. I'm going to make an edit to my post and show you the client and server side code. If you have any ideas why my JS is not being hit, I would appreciate an answer from anybody. thanks so much for your help asymptoticFault :)

Comment: I changed my JS function to the following, but still doesn't work... <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" id="ddlSubmit" value='@Resources.Add' />
            </td>
        </tr> <script>
    $('#ddlSubmit').click(function ()
    {
        var selTypeText = $("#StatusID option:selected").text();
        $("#Description").val(selTypeText);
    });
</script>